# HTML <video> colours not matching background

Tags: html, css, html5-video

On my pc, I have been hand-coding a website, and I want to include a video which autoplays on website load. I got it working fine, and using an eyedropper tool found the background colour of the video I was using. I set my page background to this colour (all the code to follow is a gross oversimplification):

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="vid">
        <!-- assume video has background of #1122ff-->
        <video src="test.mp4"></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{
    background-color:#1122ff;
}
```

When I tested the site on my PC and a friend's, the video blended perfectly with the matching background. However, on the 3 MacBooks I have tested the site on (both chrome and safari) there has been a noticable difference between the colours of the video, and of the background. I attempted to correct this by implementing JS which painted the video onto a canvas, sampled 1 pixel of the background for the colour and set the main background to this, but it changed nothing. I have no idea why this is happening, and I would be very grateful if anyone could explain why this is happening, and how to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Probable cause

Different systems has different gamma settings, and there may even be separate gamma system settings for hardware accelerated video/content overlay as well.

The actual gamma adjustment can come from a simple gamma value or an ICC profile depending on system and browser and is not available through any API in the browser. A simple gamma will affect especially mid-tones, but if gamma comes from an ICC profile any level and tone may be affected.

There is of course no simple way to handle all system and color setting combinations.

#### Possible solutions

There are no technical/visual details describing the video in question, but depending on the video content, you may be able to compensate for some by creating a mask using a div overlay combined with CSS, canvas or an image fading from outer background (CSS) color to a transparent version of it at the edges. Note that loading images may be subject to ICC/gamma conversion depending on browser.

You can also try to go the "other way", sample a frame from the video background using a canvas (or video editor and save out an image without ICC/gamma), then set that as repeated background image instead of the color.

Comment: I implemented the canvas sampling solution - you can check it out on [novusdiem.comuf.com](http://novusdiem.comuf.com). Still getting a few issues with compatibility on Macs and the like, but generally good. I am also considering making the video completely invisible and copying the data to a canvas, which should resolve the Mac issues. In any case, thank you for a great solution to a really annoying problem.